# Cannot add icon to registered document type? Is this a bug?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mime-types, uti, cfbundledocumenttypes

I am trying to add icons to the document type I have defined using Xcode document type option on the project info.

[image]
See the phrase `add icons here`? In theory you can drop icons to that area. I have tried png, ico, icns. Nothing.

I have tried to add the icons by clicking on the `+` there, nope. I click on the `+`, I choose the files and nothing happens.

The icon you see there I was able to drop to the place it is, that is another droppable place.

My problem is this:

1. I have dropped a 320x320 png to the place you see the icon.
2. I use the following code to obtain the icon at run time and display it.

   ```
   UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
   docController.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x.%@", [[fileURL path] pathExtension]]; // it is x, but it can be anything
   NSArray *icons = (NSArray *)[docController icons];
   ```

The array I get has two icons, both with the same size that is 37x48 in size (???!!!)

**two questions**

1. can you confirm if this is a bug and there is no way to add icons there?
2. can you confirm if this code is what I have to use to get the icon?

---

Apple documentation is vague. I don't know if these icons have to have a special nomenclature. My big icon is something like `bigIcon.png` and the small one is `smallIcon.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

required icon sizes are

- iPad  320x320, 64x64
- iPhone 44x58, 22x29

you have to modify .plist manually (i didn't find another way yet)

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
<array>
<string>icon320x320.png</string>
<string>icon64x64.png</string>
<string>icon44x58.png</string>
<string>icon22x29.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>mydocumenttype</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Owner</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
<string>xyz.mydocument.uti</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```